# Troubles getting false and true operator overload to work

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

say we've got the following code:

```
class A {
    public B b { get; set; }
}

class B {
    int x;
    public static bool operator true(B d1)
    {
        return d1.x > 0;
    }

    public static bool operator false(B d1)
    {
        return !(d1.x > 0);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
//A a1, a2;
if(a1.b || ( a2 != null && a2.b))
```

However, I'm getting an error saying cannot use && between bool type and "B" type. As if the bool operator wasn't working for the a2.b expression. Anyone knows what's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this a tiny bit differently to get it to work.  You just need to overload the implicit bool operator (and make sure A.b isn't null):

```
class A {
    A() { b = new B();}
    public B b { get; set; }
}
class B {
    int x;
    public static implicit operator bool(B d1) {
        return d1.x > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to also overload some additional operators for this to work as you'd expect it to. Check out [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx).

```
class A
{
    public B b { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    int x;

    public static implicit operator B(bool b) 
    {
        return b ? new B { x = 1 } : new B { x = 0 };
    }

    public static explicit operator bool(B b)
    {
        return b.x > 0;
    }

    public static bool operator true(B d1)
    {
        return d1.x > 0;
    }

    public static bool operator false(B d1)
    {
        return !(d1.x > 0);
    }

    public static B operator &(B d1, B d2) 
    {
        return d1.x > 0 && d2.x > 0;
    }

    public static B operator |(B d1, B d2)
    {
        return d1.x > 0 || d2.x > 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var a1 = new A();
    var a2 = new A();
    if (a1.b || (a2 != null && a2.b))
    {

    }
}
```

Please note that with the limited scope of the classes `A` and `B` I'm not sure how to actually handle the overloads, so I made some assumptions. Regardless, the premise is there for you. Here is the [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uG6FKN) of the working code.